# Python: retrieve dictionary keys in order as added?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, key

In Python, is there a way to retrieve the list of keys in the order in that the items were added?

```
String.compareMethods = {'equals': String.equals,
                         'contains': String.contains,
                         'startswith': String.startswith,
                         'endswith': String.endswith}
```

The keys you see here are meant for a select (dropdown) box so the order is important.

Is there a way without keeping a separate list (and without overcomplicating things for what I'm trying to do)? For what I see it's not possible due to the hashing involved...

I'm using Python 2.6.x.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) on Python 2.7+, or [`OrderedDict` from PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ordereddict) for older versions of Python. You should be able to install it for Python 2.4-2.6 with `pip install ordereddict` or `easy_install ordereddict`.

It is a subclass of `dict`, so any method that takes a `dict` will also accept an `OrderedDict`.

Comment: So, there's only the way of adding that custom dict. I'm not in the usual Python environment as most people, so I have to check whether this qualifies as "over-complicating things" for me.

Comment: @Kawu It's a single class. See http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576693/, the recipe the package is based on. You can simply copy-paste it into your existing module if you want -- nothing complicated about that.

Comment: Yes of course, but that's kinda crude. I'll probably have to do it that way as I can't foresee the version in which this script is running. Otherwise I'd have to check versions and then use some conditional logic to use the Python-supplied `OrderedDict` if in a 2.7+ env or fallback to the implementation I supply. Don't know if that's possible nor do I know if that's desirable.

Comment: @Kawu `try: from collections import OrderedDict` and `except: import OrderedDict # or your entire implementation here`

Answer (score 2):

What you need is called [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = OrderedDict();
d['equals'] = String.equals
d['contains'] = String.contains
# ...
```

Comment: Yes, but he's on Python 2.6 so there is no `collections.OrderedDict`.

Comment: Exactly, this is why I added the extra info.